# javascript array multidimensional push

Tags: javascript

i want to push value multidimensional array. But I could not success.

```
var e = [];
var data = [];  
var element = {}, items = [];
e = getelement("alan"); 

for(s=0;s < e.length ; s++ ){

element.resim = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
element.baslik = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
element.icerik = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
element.links = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
items.push(element);

}


c = JSON.stringify(items);
```

e object source:

```
'0' => "resim" '1' => "baslik" '2' => "icerik" '3' => "link"
```

c object source:

```
[
    {"resim":"4","baslik":"4","icerik":"4","links":"4"},
    {"resim":"4","baslik":"4","icerik":"4","links":"4"},
    {"resim":"4","baslik":"4","icerik":"4","links":"4"},
    {"resim":"4","baslik":"4","icerik":"4","links":"4"}
]
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Can you please describe what you're trying to achieve, so we here can help?

Answer (score 2):

You only ever store a single object in `element`

Each time you go around the loop you *edit the existing object* and then push another *reference* to it onto the array.

Create a new object each time you go around the loop.

```
for(s=0;s < e.length ; s++ ){
    element = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating a new object every time you push to the array, so you're just modifying the same object and pushing it into the array 4 times. You need to create a new object each time you loop through like so:

```
var e = [];
var data = [];  
var items = [];
e = getelement("alan"); 

for(s=0;s < e.length ; s++ ){
    var element = {};
    element.resim = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
    element.baslik = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
    element.icerik = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
    element.links = $( "#"+e[s] ).val();
    items.push(element);
}


c = JSON.stringify(items);
```